# Python pre-commit unittest faild

Tags: python, git, python-unittest, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I wish [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com) to run the tests before committing my code.
The command `python -m unittest discover` is working in the command line.

```
D:\project_dir>python -m unittest discover
...
...
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 6.743s

OK
```

But when trying to commit I am getting

```
D:\project_dir>git commit -m "fix tests with hook"
run tests................................................................Failed
hookid: tests

usage: python.exe -m unittest discover [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c]
                                       [-b] [-k TESTNAMEPATTERNS] [-s START]
                                       [-p PATTERN] [-t TOP]
python.exe -m unittest discover: error: unrecognized arguments: bigpipe_response/processors_manager.py
usage: python.exe -m unittest discover [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c]
                                       [-b] [-k TESTNAMEPATTERNS] [-s START]
                                       [-p PATTERN] [-t TOP]
python.exe -m unittest discover: error: unrecognized arguments: tests/test_processors.py
```

Here is my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file.

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: tests
        name: run tests
        entry: python -m unittest discover
        language: python
        types: [python]
        stages: [commit]
```

Also for language I try to use `system`. I got the same result.

How can I solve this? Please help.

Comment: What program are you using to run this pre-commit hook?

Comment: @magikid what do you mean by what program ?

Comment: git doesn't natively understand your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file.  All git understands are scripts in the `.git/hooks/` folder.  It looks like the program that uses this file is the [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following YAML. Of course, you should change the pattern in `args` option if you are using different one.

```
-   id: unittest
    name: unittest
    entry: python -m unittest discover 
    language: python
    'types': [python]
    args: ["-p '*test.py'"] # Probably this option is absolutely not needed.
    pass_filenames: false
    stages: [commit]
```

You should set to `false` the `pass_filenames` parameter because in other case the files will be passed as arguments and as you mentioned in your question these are "unrecognized" parameters.

Comment: thank you @milanbalazs this was very helpful. indeed is was the `pass_filenames: false`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer won't work if your application depends on some packages. In this case, the `language:python` setting lets pre-commit use a custom virtual environment (within the `~/.cache` folder), that you can add dependencies using the `additional-dependencies` flag. However this usually means copying the contents of 'requirements.txt`

So in order to use your application's virtual environment, you have to set the `language:system` setting and put your tests into the `repo: local`. Then the virtual environment that is activated when running the pre-commit hooks is used.

A working configuration would look like this:

```yaml
- repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: unittests
        name: run unit tests
        entry: python -m unittest
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        args: ["discover"]
```