# Python pre-commit unittest skipped

Tags: python, git, python-unittest, githooks, pre-commit.com

I would like to use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) to handle git hooks for my git project. However, when I use it, the `git commit` command keeps to skip the `unittest` execution:

```
(smartexchange) trnbook:SmartExchange ale$ git commit -m "add pre-commit yaml config"
autopep8.............................................(no files to check)Skipped
unittest.............................................(no files to check)Skipped
[hook_precommit da26d1e] add pre-commit yaml config
1 file changed, 14 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 .pre-commit-config.yaml
```

Same result on pre-commit hook manual execution:

```
(smartexchange) trnbook:SmartExchange ale$ pre-commit install && python .git/hooks/pre-commit
pre-commit installed at .git/hooks/pre-commit
autopep8.............................................(no files to check)Skipped
unittest.............................................(no files to check)Skipped
```

What am I missing? The manual execution of `python -m unittest discover` it's ok and it executes 4 unittest:

```
(smartexchange) trnbook:SmartExchange ale$ python -m unittest discover -s smartexchange/
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

I already read the pre-commit user docs and this answer:

[Python pre-commit unittest faild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358182/python-pre-commit-unittest-faild)

Here is my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file.

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-autopep8
    rev: ''  # Use the sha / tag you want to point at
    hooks:
    -   id: autopep8
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: unittest
        name: unittest
        entry: python -m unittest discover 
        language: python
        'types': [python]
        additional_dependencies: []
        pass_filenames: false
```

I use [miniconda](https://pre-commit.com/) as environment manager. Here my `conda list` output:

```
(smartexchange) trnbook:SmartExchange ale$ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/ale/bin/miniconda3/envs/smartexchange:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
aspy.yaml                 1.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.11.27                    0  
cached-property           1.5.1                      py_1  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0  
cfgv                      2.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
editdistance              0.5.3            py37h0a44026_0    conda-forge
identify                  1.4.9                      py_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        1.3.0                    py37_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
more-itertools            8.0.2                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
nodeenv                   1.3.3                      py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_3  
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0  
pre-commit                1.21.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.5                h359304d_0  
pyyaml                    5.2              py37h1de35cc_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
setuptools                42.0.2                   py37_0  
six                       1.13.0                   py37_0  
sqlite                    3.30.1               ha441bb4_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toml                      0.10.0           py37h28b3542_0  
virtualenv                16.7.5                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
```

The operative system I use is MacOS Catalina, version 10.15.2.

---

EDIT:

The [Anthony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59587876/5306152) is good; however it's best, for future reference, to report the revised configuration I use to run the `unittest` command (here [docs about test-discovery](https://pre-commit.com/)) with the option `--start-directory=path/to/python_module_folder`:

```
    -   id: unittest
        name: unittest
        entry: python -m unittest discover
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: [--start-directory=path/to/python_module_folder, --pattern=test_*.py]
        pass_filenames: false
        verbose: true
```

As reported by [pre-commit documentation about argument pattern in hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks), additional arguments should be in [long format](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Format.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pre-commit` will only run hooks for [files which are staged](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks) in your particular commit

this configuration:

```
    -   id: unittest
        name: unittest
        entry: python -m unittest discover 
        language: python
        'types': [python]
        additional_dependencies: []
        pass_filenames: false
```

will only run when a `types: [python]` file is matched (for `git commit` this would mean a python file would need to change for it to execute)

If you want it to run always, you can use `always_run: true` (though, you can probably save some time as it is)

If you have any python files (which would be matched by `types: [python]`), you can also trigger it by using `pre-commit run --all-files`

---

A few additional tips

- you don't need to quote `'types'` (can just use `types` since yaml supports bare words)
- `additional_dependencies: []` is the default, you can remove this line

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of `pre-commit`